# Django -- Filtering ForeignKey Drop Down in Admin Interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

From the admin interface when I access the event result form (see image below) page I want the fight drop down to only show the fights for the event in question.

[image]

Using this URL /events/eventresult/4/ **how can I make it that it only show the fights for event 4.** and not all the fights for all the events.

**admin model**

```
class EventResultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('event', 'fight', 'howitended', 'winner', 'ended_in_round', 'fight_started', 'fight_ended',)

    search_fields = ['event__name']
```

**fight model**

```
class Fight(TimeStampedModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, related_name='fights')
    fighter = models.ForeignKey(Fighter, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_fighter', null=True)
    fightstatus = models.ForeignKey('fights.FightStatus', null=True, blank=True)
    opponent = models.ForeignKey(Fighter, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_opponent', null=True)

    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    fight_highlights = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    fight_order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    post_fight_interview = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    show_fact = models.NullBooleanField(default=True, null=True)
    total_round = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} vs {}'.format(self.fighter.name, self.opponent.name)
```

Comment: Why does EventResult have a foreign key to the event, since in can be retrieved through eventresult.fight.event anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

```
if db_field.name == 'fight':
    event_result_id = request.META['PATH_INFO'].strip('/').split('/')[-1]
    event = EventResult.objects.get(pk=event_result_id)
    kwargs['queryset'] = Fight.objects.filter(event_id=event.event_id)
```

Comment: mark it as correct so that it moves to the answered section and loses the bounty